# Its possible to add actor "name" in /transition jira api?

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I used jira API with USER-XXX and when i used /transition to "Closed" i want to logs/add an other USER-YYY somewhere in tickets jira (**no in comment field**, this is the last solution for me)

it is possible to add/changes an actor name (historyMedata ?) or other way to check all closed tickets with USER-YYY ?

i try to use historyMedata but apparently i cannot change the actor's name in request.

Comment: "historyMedata" is a custom field ?

Comment: historyMedata in /transitions fields

Comment: You can do that with ScriptRunner. 
Can you check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ScriptRunner installed on your instance, you can make a script that update the field that you want with the data that you want. And set this script to the post function of the transition to "Closed".

Comment: thx , with scriptRunner, you can said "When issues is in transition to "closed", you can replace the user from an other" ? "

Comment: You can create a script with ScriptRunner that update the field. And to trigger this script you have to use workflow post function. It has an option to trigger a script.

Also, you can use Automation to trigger the script. On the trigger of the automation you choose "Issue transitioned" and you set To status "closed". And in the action of the automation you can choose "Execute a ScriptRunner script" and set the script.